# How do i capture frame every 10 seconds and send it to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to capture frames from the video which is being recorded using webcam and send the frames as base64 format encoded image or just as a jpg image every 10 seconds to the server.

I wrote the code to use the webcam, as well as i know to click or capture an image but how do i send a frame to the server every x seconds?

P.S- webcam will be online 24*7 and should send frame every x seconds

Here is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Webcam Trial </title>
        <style>
  body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            .topnav {
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #333;
            }

            .topnav a {
                float: left;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

            #container {
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 599px;
                height: 600px;
                border: 10px #333 solid;
            }
            #videoElement {
                width: 599px;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: #cc22cc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Video Demo</a>

    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Video demo</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

        </video>
    </div>
    <script>
        var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
                .then(function(stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                })
                .catch(function(err0r) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                });
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me out with this.

Edited JS part (**Used Philip's answer**, Still unable to make it work):

```
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
            .then(function(stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            });
    }
    const cnv = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(video,50,50);


    let data = cnv.toDataUrl();
    x=10000;
    function every (x) {
        let last = new Date().getTime();

        (function loop () {
            const now = new Date().getTime(),
                delta = now - last;


            if (delta >= x) {
                //capture video
                last = now;
            }

            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        })();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To capture a single frame, you need a `<canvas>` element and use its `Context2d.drawImage()`<sup>1</sup> method like so:

```
const cnv = document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0);

//2
let data = cnv.toDataURL('image/png');
```

To make that happen every `x` seconds you need a kind of interval<sup>3</sup>, may be like that:

```
 function every (x) {
   let last = new Date().getTime();

   (function loop () {
     const now = new Date().getTime(),
           delta = now - last;


     if (delta >= x) {
       //capture video
       last = now;
     }

     window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   })();
 }
```

[<sup>1</sup> draw image](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)

[<sup>2</sup> toDataUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

[<sup>3</sup> requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I am sorry but i am unable to understand on how to implement it

Comment: What is the exact thing you cannot handle??

Comment: Where am i making mistake or what changes to be done?

Comment: You need to properly wait for the document to be loaded, the camera to be attached and then start the loop. To run the loop you need to call `every(10000)`. The code above is not meant to be a copy and paste solution, it outlines the building bricks to setup something. A fully working implementation requires some more code…

Comment: please help, i am unable to proceed further. been trying from past 20 mins and more

Comment: Do you have any experience in programming? Is that the first Javascript thing for you?

Comment: Yes, i do have, i work on R and Python. And this the 2nd or 3rd thing in JS for me actually. I'm good with HTML and CSS

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me out just with this.

Comment: Have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/mrx15o6q/44/ … Even if SO isn't a coding service I just had those 5 minutes… Couldn't test it since my PC doesn't have a camera, but I guess you get the idea...